# MTLS for .net framework, not core

Tags: c#, .net, mtls

I'm tasked with implementing MTLS in .net framework, but the only resources I've been finding are for .net core. A lot of the packages we work with are old, so for the moment I have to be writing it in .net framework 4.5.2.

All the resources I've been finding are for .net core. Does anyone know if this can even be implemented in framework, and if so, have a link to somewhere detailing the process?

Comment: You mean something like this?  https://social-msdn-microsoft-com.translate.goog/Forums/es-ES/fc4c4ad2-b954-49a8-b3ec-5a9d3f09cd7e/how-to-setup-mutual-tls-using-httpclient-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral&_x_tr_sl=es&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc

Comment: Pretty much! Im chasing leads on that doc down. Hopefully the info in there will transfer to c# nicely. Thanks!

Comment: The syntax they use may be C++ but the process should be pretty much transferable. Granted, TLS1.2 is not supported below 4.6 in Framework (as it says on that forum).